# How to use get_headers when I am behind a proxy server?

Tags: php, authentication, proxy

There don't seem to have any code to set the proxy server and its authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stream_context_set_default` function.

This [blog post](http://www.pirob.com/2013/06/php-using-getheaders-and-filegetcontents-functions-behind-proxy.html) explains how to use it. Here is the code from that page.

```
<?php
// Edit the four values below
$PROXY_HOST = "proxy.example.com"; // Proxy server address
$PROXY_PORT = "1234";    // Proxy server port
$PROXY_USER = "LOGIN";    // Username
$PROXY_PASS = "PASSWORD";   // Password
// Username and Password are required only if your proxy server needs basic authentication

$auth = base64_encode("$PROXY_USER:$PROXY_PASS");
stream_context_set_default(
 array(
  'http' => array(
   'proxy' => "tcp://$PROXY_HOST:$PROXY_PORT",
   'request_fulluri' => true,
   'header' => "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth"
   // Remove the 'header' option if proxy authentication is not required
  )
 )
);

$url = "http://www.pirob.com/";

print_r( get_headers($url) );

echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```